# How to print "The key(element) is not present in your array" when I don't enter a key present in my array when asked for by the computer in my code

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, linear-search

Let's say I enter `{1,3,3,5}` as my array and I input 6 when asked to enter the key whose index I want to know. How do I edit my code to print that "the key entered is not in your array"?

My code is given below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void linearsearch(int arr[], int n, int key) {
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == key) {
      cout << " \nthe index is: " << i;
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  int n;

  cout << "enter the size of your array : ";

  cin >> n;

  int arr[n];

  cout << "\nenter the keys of your array: ";

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> arr[i];
  }

  int key;

  cout << "\n enter the key whose index you want to know: ";

  cin >> key;

  linearsearch(arr, n, key);
}
```

Comment: Why so many blank lines in your code?  It makes it really hard to read.

Comment: You need to keep track of whether the number was found or not.

Comment: Hint: what if your `linearsearch` function returned `true` if the number was found and `false` if not?

Comment: @Botje That wouldn't work if there are same numbers in an array , it would show the index of the first occurrence of that number and terminate the function.

Comment: I never said your function had to return after finding one element.

Comment: @Botje I can't figure that out , may you please comment the code ?

Comment: Second hint: `bool linearsearch(int arr[], int n, int key) { bool found = false; ... ; return found; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// You can use a boolean control variable in the void function and when you find the number you can set its value to true and insert an if statement at the end of the loop to check the value of the bool variable, if the, if statement in the loop wasn't executed, meant that the number was not found and the value of the variable was false so it would print the line you were asking about //

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void linearsearch(int arr[], int n, int key) {
  int i;
    bool found = false;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == key) {
      cout << " \nthe index is: " << i;
      found = true;
    }
  }
  if (found == false){
    cout << "The key entered is not in your array." << endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  int n;

  cout << "enter the size of your array : ";

  cin >> n;

  int arr[n];

  cout << "\nenter the keys of your array: ";

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> arr[i];
  }

  int key;

  cout << "\n enter the key whose index you want to know: ";

  cin >> key;

  linearsearch(arr, n, key);
}
```